# Strange behavior with tagsoup and Groovy's XmlSlurper

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy, tag-soup

Let's say I want to parse the phone number from an an xml string like this:

```
str = """ <root> 
            <address>123 New York, NY 10019
                <div class="phone"> (212) 212-0001</div> 
            </address> 
        </root> 
    """
parser = new XmlSlurper(new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()).parseText (str)
println parser.address.div.text()
```

It doesn't print the phone number.

If I change the "div" element to "foo" like this

```
str = """ <root> 
            <address>123 New York, NY 10019
                <foo class="phone"> (212) 212-0001</foo> 
            </address> 
        </root> 
    """
parser = new XmlSlurper(new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()).parseText (str)
println parser.address.foo.text()
```

Then its able to parse  and print the phone number.

What the heck is going on?

Btw I am using groovy 1.7.5 and tagsoup 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Just change code to

```
println parser.address.'div'.text()
```

This is curse of Groovy and many other dynamic language - "div" is reserved method name thus you don't get node but rather try to divide "address" node :)

Comment: your explanation seems plausible but your code suggestion didn't work for me in the groovy console.

Comment: yes, sorry about not checking it with exact configuration you had. Looks like it works fine when you use standard JDK parser so the issue might be in TagSoup parser.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that tagsoup normalizes HTML tags - i.e. it uppercases them. So the GPath expression you want is probably

```
println parser.ADDRESS.DIV.text()
```

I find it handy to be able to print out the result of the parse - then you can see why your GPath isn't working. Use this..

```
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(parser)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is very old. But I faced recently and this is what I used:

```
parser.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'div' && it.@class.text() == 'phone' }.each { div ->
    println div.text()
}
```

1. Using depthFirst find all tags
2. Filter by name **div** that has class **phone**;
3. Print the value **(212) 212-0001**

Groovy version is 2.4